# How to display object data only if datetime in object is > than specified?

Tags: php

Simply i have queried an api to return some data for a game. The result is an array where each set contains epoch datecreated field.

Using php i want to be able to filter out all the data for only data containing datecreated > 1444639042(epoch time).

How is that possible?

I am using leaguewrap from github as my class to pull data so:

```
// Get Match History
$game = $api->game();
$games = $game->recent($loluser);
```

returns:

```
{
"games": [
  {
     "fellowPlayers": [
        {
           "championId": 84,
           "teamId": 200,
           "summonerId": 4972120
        },
        {
           "championId": 23,
           "teamId": 200,
           "summonerId": 1011313
        },
        {
           "championId": 18,
           "teamId": 100,
           "summonerId": 456905
        },
        {
           "championId": 77,
           "teamId": 100,
           "summonerId": 2751172
        },
        {
           "championId": 131,
           "teamId": 100,
           "summonerId": 5100445
        },
        {
           "championId": 1,
           "teamId": 200,
           "summonerId": 841536
        },
        {
           "championId": 99,
           "teamId": 200,
           "summonerId": 4400359
        },
        {
           "championId": 18,
           "teamId": 200,
           "summonerId": 3652614
        },
        {
           "championId": 80,
           "teamId": 100,
           "summonerId": 600691
        }
     ],
     "gameType": "MATCHED_GAME",
     "stats": {
        "totalDamageDealtToChampions": 17713,
        "goldEarned": 11117,
        "item1": 3174,
        "wardPlaced": 15,
        "totalDamageTaken": 19563,
        "item0": 1056,
        "trueDamageDealtPlayer": 4,
        "physicalDamageDealtPlayer": 10423,
        "trueDamageDealtToChampions": 4,
        "killingSprees": 1,
        "playerRole": 2,
        "totalUnitsHealed": 3,
        "playerPosition": 4,
        "level": 16,
        "magicDamageDealtToChampions": 16682,
        "turretsKilled": 2,
        "magicDamageDealtPlayer": 81369,
        "neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle": 3,
        "assists": 9,
        "magicDamageTaken": 11659,
        "numDeaths": 5,
        "totalTimeCrowdControlDealt": 326,
        "largestMultiKill": 1,
        "physicalDamageTaken": 7526,
        "sightWardsBought": 2,
        "team": 100,
        "win": false,
        "totalDamageDealt": 91797,
        "largestKillingSpree": 5,
        "totalHeal": 2398,
        "item4": 3135,
        "item3": 3020,
        "item6": 3340,
        "item5": 3165,
        "minionsKilled": 59,
        "timePlayed": 2852,
        "physicalDamageDealtToChampions": 1025,
        "championsKilled": 5,
        "trueDamageTaken": 377,
        "goldSpent": 9620,
        "neutralMinionsKilled": 3
     },
     "gameId": 107038398,
     "ipEarned": 82,
     "spell1": 3,
     "teamId": 100,
     "spell2": 7,
     "gameMode": "CLASSIC",
     "mapId": 11,
     "level": 30,
     "invalid": false,
     "subType": "NORMAL",
     "createDate": 1444289569012,
     "championId": 99
  }
]}
```

Comment: Show us your data / code and [what you have tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @Epodax createDate is what i am checking and that example is just one game. Does that give a better idea? Also in regards to what i have tried, its nothing because i dont know if its possible to filter an object based on value specified and still pull all data for that game.